# Eloquent not returning polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have four models; User, Profile, CorporateProfile, UserProfile. Am using the the UserProfile table to store polymorphic relations between the User models and Profile & CorporateProfileModels.
My db looks like this

```
Users
-id
-email
-password

UserProfile
-id
-profile_photo
-profle_header
-state_id
-city_id
-street
-phone
-url
-profileable_id
-profileable_type

Profile
-id
-user_id
-sex
-dob
-school_id

CorporateProfile
-id
-user_id
-industry_id
-description
-slug
```

My models

```
//User model
class User extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $with = array('profile','groups');

        public function profile()
        {
            return $this->morphOne('UserProfile', 'profileable');
        }
    }

//UserProfile Model
class UserProfile extends Eloquent 
   {

        protected $table = 'user_profiles';

        public function profileable()
        {
            return $this->morphTo();
        }
    }
```

Why try this after creating the necessary models on the db, i get an empty result

```
$user = User::find(1);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($user->profile);
            echo "</pre>";
```

Am i using the eloquent relationship properly?

Comment: Please, show data from your DB, have you tried to save UserProfile?

Comment: @DmytroGaliievskyi yes i dummy information on the db

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://www.richardbagshaw.co.uk/laravel-user-types-and-polymorphic-relationships/ it explains perfectly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the exact same prolbem right now